# how to find paid interest and principal amount from EMI Amount and Installment No

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to write a scaler value function for get Interest and Principal Amount of particular Installment from Given EMIAmount,RateOfInterest,LoanPeriod and Principal Amount
like
P=100000 (Principal Amount)

I=10 (IntrestRate)

T=24M (LoanPeriod)

EMI=4614.49 (EMIAmount)

Installment No. : 7 (EMINumber)

how to get Interest of 7th EMI from scaler value function

output should be : 640.29

please share formula or code

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. Nor have you explained anything about the values provided (though many with area expertise might be able to guess). I suggest you try searching the internet first.

Comment: i need formula not code

Comment: i get this from temp table but scaler value function not allowed create table